# "others also liked" sidebar

Tags: sidebar

We have a sidebar that says "others also liked" but what is it basing that off of? We don't have a "like" feature and the products don't have any rhyme or reason. If you click reload it's just another random 3 products.

Is there a way to control that sidebar?

Comment: It turns out that "others also liked" was designed but basically it's just the "related products" options that were empty. So I added a few related products and voila, they appeared. I guess when Magento options are empty it just puts a random set of products out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is highly dependent on your theme.

turn on the template path hints and see what template and what block render that section. then you will find the code.

Comment: Turns out it WAS dependent on the theme and just reworded as a related products option that was always available.